# Why HackerRank always gives Segmentation fault?

Tags: linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I was solving a linked list problem where I had to sum first and last nodes and return the max sum. e.g: 3-->1-->1-->3. so the program will add 0th and (n-1)th index values(3+3=6) then add 1st and (n-2)th index value (1+1 = 2). Since 6>2, it will return 6.
its similar to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-linked-list-alternate-first-last-element/

## Code

```
 void reverseList(SinglyLinkedListNode* head)
{
  SinglyLinkedListNode* prev = NULL;
  SinglyLinkedListNode* curr = head;
  SinglyLinkedListNode* next = NULL;

  while(curr)
 {
   next = curr->next;
   curr->next= prev;
   prev = curr;
   curr = next;
 }
  head = prev;

}

int maximumPages(SinglyLinkedListNode* head)  **<---start**
{
 SinglyLinkedListNode* slow = head;
 SinglyLinkedListNode* fast = slow->next;

  //finding middle of linked list
  while(fast && fast->next)
 {
   slow = slow->next;
   fast = fast->next->next;
 }

  //split the list in two
  SinglyLinkedListNode* head1 = head;
  SinglyLinkedListNode* head2 = slow->next;
  slow->next = NULL;

  //reverse the second list
  reverseList(head2);

  //calculate max pages
  int maxi = INT_MIN;
  int sum = 0;

 SinglyLinkedListNode* ptr1 = head1;
 SinglyLinkedListNode* ptr2 = head2;
 while(ptr1 || ptr2)
 {
   sum = ptr1->data + ptr2->data;
   maxi = max(maxi, sum);

   ptr1 = ptr1->next;
   ptr2 = ptr2->next;
 }

   return maxi;     **<---end**
}
```

I checked multiple times but couldn't find anything unusual with the code. Can someone please tell me where is the segmentation fault?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code seems much too complicated for the problem you describe. How short can the list be?  And what test cases have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the exception on this line:

```
sum = ptr1->data + ptr2->data;
```

`ptr2` could be `NULL`, because the left list could be one longer than the other one. The `while` condition does not prevent this from happening. You should change it to a stronger condition, using `&&` instead of `||`:

```
while(ptr1 && ptr2)
```

There is another issue though: the reversal will not change the value of the main program's `head2` variable. The function only changes the local variable with the same name. You could solve this in several ways. One is to let the function *return* the new head of the list after reversal:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode * reverseList(SinglyLinkedListNode* head)
{
  // ...all your code ..., and add:
  return head;
}
```

Then in your main code:

```
head2 = reverseList(head2);
```